# Can I have access to break my Windows BitLocker key

Tags: shors-algorithm, cryptography

Is it possible to have access to a quantum computer to break a BitLocker key (maybe with Shor's algorithm) and have access to my data?

Here what happened to me: after I've changed my LENOVO X270 laptop faulty RAM and internal keyboard, now at boot there is a Bitlocker screen it is asking me for a BitLocker key! I don't have it in my Microsoft/OneDrive account, on a printout I saved, on a USB flash drive, in an Azure Active Directory, held by a system administrator or whatsoever! This is logical: despite BitLocker comes preinstalled in Windows but I never ran and less configured it! Please trust me, I am in IT for +30 years and even if I had Alzheimer's disease I will remember it!

So, after googling and searching on Microsoft KB, I've found out that there are thousands (if not millions) of Windows users to whom it happened too. I believe it was triggered by a Windows system update and security measures which I never ever set!

I've obviously contacted Microsoft Support, checked since the past sleepless 3 weeks a lot of KBs, forums tried many prompt commands, BIOS settings, watched hours of videos, contacted recovery software companies (like Elcomsoft, Passware, TheGrideon...) all of them said their product cannot help in my case because my drive was encrypted with a numeric password which is a recovery key.

I didn't want to reinstall Windows or bring my laptop to a hardware recovery store as I don't want to take the risk to make my data unrecoverable and also if I cannot find a solution, I am definitely going to hire a lawyer and file a class-action lawsuit against Microsoft: to all Windows users to whom it happened, please contact me.

(mayThanks.
[image]

Comment: Bitlocker is using the AES encryption algorithm. With it, quantum computing won't help too much in the foreseeable future. But the hope dies the last time.

Comment: I think that this question should be closed, since it contributes to misinformation (this is not possible for the moment and no one should think that) and promotes unauthorized/illegal behavior (Microsoft wouldn't like the cracking of such a key).

Comment: Why is it misinformation? This is not an illegal behavior but BitLocker happened to be a bad product with a lot of bugs and that made millions Windows users' lives turn to hell for losing their valuable data.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there exist no quantum computer, let alone one that we 'as ordinary citizens' could have access to. It will likely take another $15$ years (although the exact timeframe is heavily debated) before there will be a quantum computer that is powerful enough to run Shor's algorithm for a key that is actually interesting to break - and getting access to one for personal use might be a stretch for another $10$ years.

Moreover, Shor's algorithm only 'works' for certain kind of *public* key encryption standards, especially the widely used RSA. A quick search tells me that windows bitlocker uses AES (which is a *private/symmetric* key encryption standard*) - a quantum computer is not gonna be able to have much speedup over classical computers in trying to crack this; this is a known fact.

All in all, a quantum computer, even if it did exist - which it does not - will not be able to help you here. Best of luck with getting back your data; and your question might get more traction on the cryptography stack exchange - but AES is a very robust encryption standard and there's probably more fruitful approaches to getting your data back than trying to crack the key.

*It makes way more sense to use symmetric key encryption here, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for this great answer!